# How can I reach the values of an array that is inside an object that is part of an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

In my componentWillMount, I have a function that calls for a 'shopping cart' field inside the current user's doc.

This shopping cart field is an array of objects, and each object has a field that contains an array of image URLs.

My problem is that I declare my desired variable 'shoppingCart' in my component's state and then in the componentWillMount, I assign this value the returned array of objects (shopping cart objects).

When I test to see if I can acquire the first link of the array inside one of the objects, the program complains that the field is undefined and proceeds to crash. I noticed that depending on how I declare my state variable I can acquire more or less information from these objects.

For Example:

If I declare my state variable like this:

```
this.state={
shoppingCart:"",
}
```

Then I can only get to the object in shoppingCart[n],

But if I declare my state like this:

```
this.state={
shoppingCart:[{}],
}
```

I can go into the field of the object of my choosing for example:

```
shoppingCart[n].name;
```

But when it comes to trying to get one of the values of an array inside the object for example:

```
shoppingCart[n].url[n]
```

This isn't possible.

Do I have to declare the state variable a certain way?

```
export const getCartItems = (props) => {

return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
       const firebase = getFirebase();
       const firestore = getFirestore();
        const storage = firebase.storage();


    return 
    firestore.collection('users').doc(props.auth.uid).get().then((user)=>{
        return user.data().shoppingCart;
        })

    }

}


constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
             shoppingCart: [{}],
        }

     }


    componentWillMount() {

        if (this.props.auth.uid) {
        this.props.getCartItems(this.props).then((shoppingCart) => {
            this.setState({
                shoppingCart,
            })
        })


    }
}
```

Comment: That's a perfectly fine way to get to the inner array, what/where is the issue?

Comment: "...`shoppingCart[n].url[n]` this isn't possible." Why not? What happens when you try? Is the `url` property really an array? Do you really want the same index in the `shoppingCard` array and the `url` array? Also please show an example of the objects and arrays that you are working with.

Comment: Are you storing an array of urls in each shopping cart? Try shoppingCart[n].url

Comment: Most likely the `n`th url of the `n`th shopping card doesn't exist. Why would you expect these two indices to be the same?

Comment: So the 'n' value is was just an example, the index of the url and the the current item can be different

Comment: in the promise in the componentWillMount I get the shopping cart and when I do the whole shoppingCart[m].url[n] and it works just find the problem is when I try to do the same thing with that same value assigned to the state variable it doesnt let me acquire the same field, thats why i think it has to do with the state variable declaration @PeterCheng

Comment: So you are storing an array of urls in url? You may want to rename it to 'urls'

Comment: agreed but the name isnt the problem its when i assign the returned shopping cart to the shopping cart state variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare your initial state to be `{ shoppingCart: [{}] }`, you are saying to load one shopping cart with no fields. If you try to access url of an empty object you will get `undefined`. If you try to access the nth element of undefined, you will get a runtime error.

After you call the promise, there is a bit of time before your response is loaded into state. In that time, your initial state needs to protect against cases where you are accessing fields of undefined as described above.

Two viable options are either

```
this.state = { shoppingCart: [] };
```

or

```
this.state = { shoppingCart: [ { url: [] } ] };
```

Lastly, another solution involves having no default state, but having a conditional reference every time you reference state.

Comment: You're just guessing here, we have no idea what the structure is of the data returned from `getCartItems()` and we have no idea where/how OP is trying to access the data in the way he/she described it.

Comment: so pretty much the data is ordered like this: [{name,description, price, url [ link1, link2,link3  ] },{same thing here},{same thing here}]. obviously the size of the array depends on how many items are in the cart @YannickK

Comment: I can access the data just fine inside the promise variable but when i assign the value to the state variable I can't navigate its fields, once again i think its because the state and promise variable are different in terms of structure

Comment: Are you getting undefined or a TypeError?

Comment: @PeterCheng your answer worked, I guess i had to define the field as well in the state variable? Thanks for the help! just to clarify it was the second one

Comment: @LuisF. I'll edit my post to explain a little more.